# Error when running mvn archetype:generate

Tags: java, maven, maven-2

I'm trying to run a maven command to generate a project structure, but I get the following error :

> Failed to resolve artifact, possibly due to a repository list that is not appropriately equipped for this artifact's metadata.
>     org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:pom:3.0.2-SNAPSHOT

I think that the problem is that maven is using version 3.0.2-SNAPSHOT of **maven-archetype-plugin** but I don't where I can change it.
I also looked in the repository in which mvn search the artifact and I didn't find this version.

does anyone know whatis the problem or where I can change the *version of maven-archetype-plugin* 

**UPDATE**
I'm using **Maven 2.2.1**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try running it that way: `mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.0.1:generate`.

This will force the `maven-archetype-plugin` version to use.

As seen [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.maven.plugins/maven-archetype-plugin), there is no version above 3.0.1